# Prove that $A\cap \partial D\neq\varnothing$ under some conditions

Tags: general-topology

Let $A, B$ and $D$ be non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

> Assume that
>
> - $A\cap \partial B\neq\varnothing$
> - $B\subset D$.
> - $\overline{B}=\overline{D}$.
>
> Is $A\cap \partial D\neq\varnothing$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Take $B=\mathbb Q, A=D=\mathbb R$ for a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you. Please if in addition the sets $A,B$ and $D$ are bounded, is the claim can be true? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler Still false. Take $A=(0,1), B=\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ and $D=[0,1]$.